# Mostra JDateChooser y ComboBox en un TextArea

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox, jdatechooser

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la escuela, la maestra nos dejó elegir un tema con algún tutorial de YouTube y el tema que elegí fue un sistema de facturación para clientes, pero debemos añadirles otros controles y completar el programa para que funcione mejor y se vea bien visualmente, este es el video del que saqué el tema:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://youtu.be/xpkiGakG8C8?si=PmilEeEqBnksaeNL)
Tengo un problema y es que no se como mostrar la opción seleccionada del JDateChooser y el ComboBox en el TextArea.
Este es código que use, lo saqué del video ya mencionado y es el botón total.

```
 private void btntotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    itemcost[0]= Double.parseDouble(txtali.getText()) * 5.00;
    itemcost[1]= Double.parseDouble(txtbol.getText()) * 4.00;
    itemcost[2]= Double.parseDouble(txtpat.getText()) * 3.00;
    itemcost[3]= Double.parseDouble(txtpes.getText()) * 3.50;
    itemcost[4]= Double.parseDouble(txtpoll.getText()) * 4.50;
    itemcost[5]= Double.parseDouble(txtcho.getText()) * 1.50;
    itemcost[6]= Double.parseDouble(txtco.getText()) * 2.00;
    itemcost[7]= Double.parseDouble(txtmen.getText()) * 1.90;

    itemcost[8] = itemcost[0] + itemcost[1] + itemcost[2] + itemcost[3] + itemcost[4];
    itemcost[9] = itemcost[5] + itemcost[6] + itemcost[7];

    itemcost[10] = itemcost[8] + itemcost[9];
    iIva = String.format("$ %.2f", itemcost[10]*12/100);
    iSubTotal = String.format("$ %.2f", itemcost[10]);
    iTotal = String.format("$ %.2f", itemcost[10] + (itemcost[10]*12/100));

    txtiva.setText(iIva);
    txtsubt.setText(iSubTotal);
    txttotal.setText(iTotal);

    //========================================================================
    txtrecibo.setEnabled(true);
    //========================================================================
    int refs=1235 + (int) (Math.random()*4238);

    //========================================================================
    Calendar timer= Calendar.getInstance();
    timer.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat tTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    tTime.format(timer.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat Tdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-aaaa");
    Tdate.format(timer.getTime());
    //========================================================================
    txtrecibo.append("\tSistema de facturación a clientes\n"+
        "Reference:\t\t\t" + refs +
        "\n=====================================================\t " +

        "\n=====================================================\t " +
        "\nNombre:\t\t\t" + txtnombre.getText() +
        "\nApellido:\t\t\t" + txtapellido.getText() +
        "\nDirección:\t\t\t" + txtdirec.getText() +
        "\nGmail:\t\t\t" + txtgmail.getText() +
        "\nCédula:\t\t\t" + txtcedu.getText() +
        "\nAlitas Mixtas:\t\t\t" + txtali.getText() +
        "\nBolón con café:\t\t\t" + txtbol.getText() +
        "\nPatacones:\t\t\t" + txtpat.getText() +
        "\nPescado:\t\t\t" + txtpes.getText() +
        "\nPollo:\t\t\t" + txtpoll.getText() +
        "\nHeladoChocolate:\t\t\t" + txtcho.getText() +
        "\nHeladoCoco:\t\t\t" + txtco.getText() +
        "\nHeladoMenta:\t\t\t" + txtmen.getText() +

        "\n=====================================================\t " +

        "\nIva:\t\t\t" + iIva +
        "\nSubTotal:\t\t\t" + iSubTotal +
        "\nTotal:\t\t\t" + iTotal +
        "\n=====================================================\t " +
        "\nHora: " + Tdate.format(timer.getTime()) +
        "n\n\tGracias por visitar PlazaBeach\n" );

}
```

Así es como se ve mi programa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
También me podrían ayudar a solucionar donde dice Hora en el TextArea se muestra la fecha del dia y los minutos de la hora, pero no se muestra exactamente la hora o el dia que es, por ejemplo hoy es 28 y son las 10:42 en el TextArea aparece de esta forma 28-42-PMn y no entiendo por que

Comment: Hola Leila, para la fecha, reemplaza **dd-mm-aaaa** por **"dd-MM-yyyy"** y para el **DateChooser**, puedes usar: 
      **try { 
         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
         String theDate = dateFormat.format( selectorDeFecha.getDate() );
      }
      catch( Exception ex ) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Debes seleccioinar una fecha" );
      }**.

Answer (score 1):

Me funcionó, y me di cuenta que lo único que tenía que hacer era cambiar el getText por getDate para que se mostrara en el TextArea. Ahora con eso me surge una duda, ¿Qué debo poner para el ComboBox? y ¿es posible cambiar la fecha de inglés a español?. Gracias.

```
private void btntotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   
    itemcost[0]= Double.parseDouble(txtali.getText()) * 5.00;
    itemcost[1]= Double.parseDouble(txtbol.getText()) * 4.00;
    itemcost[2]= Double.parseDouble(txtpat.getText()) * 3.00;
    itemcost[3]= Double.parseDouble(txtpes.getText()) * 3.50;
    itemcost[4]= Double.parseDouble(txtpoll.getText()) * 4.50;
    itemcost[5]= Double.parseDouble(txtcho.getText()) * 1.50;
    itemcost[6]= Double.parseDouble(txtco.getText()) * 2.00;
    itemcost[7]= Double.parseDouble(txtmen.getText()) * 1.90;

    itemcost[8] = itemcost[0] + itemcost[1] + itemcost[2] + itemcost[3] + itemcost[4];
    itemcost[9] = itemcost[5] + itemcost[6] + itemcost[7];

    itemcost[10] = itemcost[8] + itemcost[9];
    iIva = String.format("$ %.2f", itemcost[10]*12/100);
    iSubTotal = String.format("$ %.2f", itemcost[10]);
    iTotal = String.format("$ %.2f", itemcost[10] + (itemcost[10]*12/100));

    txtiva.setText(iIva);
    txtsubt.setText(iSubTotal);
    txttotal.setText(iTotal);

    //========================================================================
    txtrecibo.setEnabled(true);
    //========================================================================
    int refs=1235 + (int) (Math.random()*4238);

    //========================================================================
    Calendar timer= Calendar.getInstance();
    timer.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat tTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    tTime.format(timer.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat Tdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Tdate.format(timer.getTime());
    //========================================================================
    txtrecibo.append("\tSistema de facturación a clientes\n"+
        "Reference:\t\t\t" + refs +
        "\n=====================================================\t " +

        "\n=====================================================\t " +
        "\nFecha-Entrada:\t\t\t" + jDateChooser1.getDate() +    
        "\nFecha-Salida:\t\t\t" + jDateChooser2.getDate() +    
        "\n=====================================================\t " +
        "\nNombre:\t\t\t" + txtnombre.getText() +
        "\nApellido:\t\t\t" + txtapellido.getText() +
        "\nDirección:\t\t\t" + txtdirec.getText() +
        "\nGmail:\t\t\t" + txtgmail.getText() +
        "\nCédula:\t\t\t" + txtcedu.getText() +
        "\nF-Nacimiento:\t\t\t" + jDateChooser3.getDate() +
        "\nAlitas Mixtas:\t\t\t" + txtali.getText() +
        "\nBolón con café:\t\t\t" + txtbol.getText() +
        "\nPatacones:\t\t\t" + txtpat.getText() +
        "\nPescado:\t\t\t" + txtpes.getText() +
        "\nPollo:\t\t\t" + txtpoll.getText() +
        "\nHeladoChocolate:\t\t\t" + txtcho.getText() +
        "\nHeladoCoco:\t\t\t" + txtco.getText() +
        "\nHeladoMenta:\t\t\t" + txtmen.getText() +

        "\n=====================================================\t " +

        "\nIva:\t\t\t" + iIva +
        "\nSubTotal:\t\t\t" + iSubTotal +
        "\nTotal:\t\t\t" + iTotal +
        "\n=====================================================\t " +
        "\nHora: " + tTime.format(timer.getTime()) +    
        "\nFecha: " + Tdate.format(timer.getTime()) +
        "n\n\tGracias por visitar PlazaBeach\n" );

    try 
    { 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" ); 
        String theDate = dateFormat.format( jDateChooser1.getDate() ); } 
        catch( Exception ex ) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Debes seleccionar una fecha" ); 
        }
}
```

Así se ve :D
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Vas muy bien, pero estás repitiendo código innecesariamente, por ejemplo acá:

```
itemcost[0]= Double.parseDouble(txtali.getText()) * 5.00;
itemcost[1]= Double.parseDouble(txtbol.getText()) * 4.00;
itemcost[2]= Double.parseDouble(txtpat.getText()) * 3.00;
itemcost[3]= Double.parseDouble(txtpes.getText()) * 3.50;
itemcost[4]= Double.parseDouble(txtpoll.getText()) * 4.50;
itemcost[5]= Double.parseDouble(txtcho.getText()) * 1.50;
itemcost[6]= Double.parseDouble(txtco.getText()) * 2.00;
itemcost[7]= Double.parseDouble(txtmen.getText()) * 1.90;

itemcost[8] = itemcost[0] + itemcost[1] + itemcost[2] + itemcost[3] + itemcost[4];
itemcost[9] = itemcost[5] + itemcost[6] + itemcost[7];
```

Por suerte son "8" item's, sino sería una "sabana", siempre puedes recurrir a los array, te hacen la vida más sencilla.

```
double itemCost[] = new double[ 10 ];
double valorExtraño[] = { 5.00, 4.00, 3.00, 3.50, 4.50, 1.50, 2.00, 1.90 };
JTextField campos[] = { txtali, txtbol, txtpat, txtpes, txtpoll, txtcho, txtco, txtmen };
for( int i = 0; i < campos.length; i++ ) {
    itemCost[ i ] = Double.parseDouble( campos[ i ].getText()) * valorExtraño[ i ];
    if( i < 5 ) {
        itemCost[ 8 ] += itemCost[ i ];
    }
    else {
        itemCost[ 9 ] += itemCost[ i ];
    }
}
```

Si quieres ir un poco más lejos...

```
JTextField campos[] = new JTextField[ 8 ];
int loc[] = { 100, 100, 80, 26 }; 
for( int i = 0; i < campos.length; i++ ) {
    campos[ i ] = new JTextField();
    campos[ i ].setBounds( loc[ 0 ], loc[ 1 ], loc[ 2 ], loc[ 3 ] );
    campos[ i ].setForegroundColor( Color.red );

       // con esta linea, modificas el valor que será asignando a las "y", 
       // haciendo que cada nuevo campo de texto, este debajo del anterior
    loc[ 1 ] += 35;
}
```

Esto último no es que lo tengas que aplicar, es solo una muestra de como "abreviarte" la codificación.

Ahora saltemos a:

```
Calendar timer= Calendar.getInstance();
timer.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat tTime = new SimpleDateFormat( "hh:mm:ss" );
tTime.format( timer.getTime() );
SimpleDateFormat Tdate = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
Tdate.format( timer.getTime() );

blablabla...

"\n=====================================================\t " +
"\nHora: " + Tdate.format( timer.getTime() ) +
"n\n\tGracias por visitar PlazaBeach\n" );
```

Cuando escribes **timer.getTime();**, estás llamando a una función que devuelve algo, un objeto que queda en la nada, ya que no lo asignas a ninguna variable, luego, cuando realmente usas ese objeto, vuelves a hacer todo el proceso (en la ante-última linea), sería más "económico" así:

```
Calendar timer= Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat tTime = new SimpleDateFormat( "hh:mm:ss" );
SimpleDateFormat Tdate = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" );

blablabla...

"\n=====================================================\t " +
"\nHora: " + Tdate.format( timer.getTime() ) +
"n\n\tGracias por visitar PlazaBeach\n"
```

A pesar de las correcciones, te puedo decir que vas muy bien, y no te desalientes, todos empezamos igual...

Ahhh me olvidé, lo de las fechas,  podes hacerlo así:

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "es", "ES" );      
Calendar hoy = Calendar.getInstance();      
System.out.println("hoy es " + 
        timer.getDisplayName( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, locale ) +
        " " +  
        timer.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) + 
        " de " + 
        timer.getDisplayName( Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, locale ) + 
        " de " + 
        timer.get( Calendar.YEAR ) );
```

Para obtener el texto seleccionado el un **JComboBox** podes usar:

```
   // en el cuerpo del método que recibe el evento
public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent event ) {
    if( event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED ) {
        String texto = event.getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

Podes modificar esto, por ejemplo en lugar de crear una cadena, el texto lo envías directamente a donde necesitas mostrarlo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. <3

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!